# What is the opposite colloquial expression of eating cheap?

Tags: phrase-requests, colloquialisms

I heard people using colloquial expressions like "I like to eat cheap". What is the opposite colloquial expression of eating cheap? Is it eating expensive? I tried googling "eat expensive", but found no expected results.

Comment: Dining well, among others.

Comment: High on the hog.

Comment: "Eating high on the hog" is, as Hot Licks notes, a very colloquial expression for eating expensive things. Other options include "eating fancy," "ritzy dining," "eating at white tablecloth [or "cloth napkin"] restaurants," and "going uptown." I suspect that there are many localized terms as well. One guy I know says, "I like eating at places where the menu isn't posted on a big drive-through display, and you don't have to place your order by talking to a giant clown tthough a nicrophone."

Comment: If you say 'dining out' the implication is a sit down restaurant and that phrase isn't commonly associated with cheap eats like fast food.

Comment: “You like eating cheap?  I’m more of a *fine dining* kind of a guy.”